# pull Drupal field values with db_query() or db_select()

Tags: database, drupal

I've created a content type in Drupal 7 with 5 or 6 fields. Now I want to use a function to query them in a hook_view call back. I thought I would query the node table but all I get back are the nid and title. How do I get back the values for my created fields using the database abstraction API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal stores the fields in other tables and can automatically join them in. The storage varies depending on how the field is configured so the easiest way to access them is by using an [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7). It'll handle the complexity of joining all your fields in. There's some good examples of how to use it here: http://drupal.org/node/1343708

But if you're working in [hook_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_view/7), you should already be able access the values, they're loaded into the $node object that's passed in as a parameter. Try running:

```
debug($node);
```

In your hook and you should see all the properties.

Comment: I should have said hook_block_view where I am using a module to pull data, insert it into a block and then passing it to theme function for display on the page. Since some of the fields are to position the element, I want the raw data in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you already known the ID of the nodes (nid) you want to load, you should use the [`node_load_multiple()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7) to load them. This will load the complete need with all fields value. To search the node id, [`EntityFieldQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) is the recommended way but it has [some limitations](http://drupal.org/project/issues/drupal?text=EntityFieldQuery&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=All&version=All&component=All). You can also use the database API to query the `node` table for the `nid` (and revision ID, `vid`) of your nodes, then load them using `node_load_multiple()`.

Loading a complete load can have performance impacts since it will load way more data than what you need. If this prove to be an issue, you can either try do directly access to field storage tables (if your fields values are stored in your SQL database). The schema of these tables is buld *dynamicaly* depedning on the fields types, cardinality and other settings. You will have to dig into your database schema to figure it out. And it will probably change as soon as you change something on your fields.

Another solution, is to build *stub* node entities and to use [`field_attach_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_load/7) with a `$options['field_id']` value to only load the value of a specific field. But this require a good knowledge and understanding of the Field API.

Comment: Thanks that helps, too. I'll test both methods of pulling the nodes with fields and see what I can do.

Comment: @bradrice: Don't forget to click the 'up' arrow for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to use EntityFieldQuery](https://drupal.org/node/1343708) article in Drupal Community Documentation.

> Creating A Query
>
> Here is a basic query looking for all articles with a photo that are
>   tagged as a particular faculty member and published this year. In the
>   last 5 lines of the code below, the $result variable is populated with
>   an associative array with the first key being the entity type and the
>   second key being the entity id (e.g., $result['node'][12322] = partial
>   node data). Note the $result won't have the 'node' key when it's
>   empty, thus the check using isset, this is explained [here](http://drupal.org/node/1427098).

Example:

```
<?php
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->fieldCondition('field_news_types', 'value', 'spotlight', '=')
  ->fieldCondition('field_photo', 'fid', 'NULL', '!=')
  ->fieldCondition('field_faculty_tag', 'tid', $value)
  ->fieldCondition('field_news_publishdate', 'value', $year. '%', 'like')
  ->fieldOrderBy('field_photo', 'fid', 'DESC')
  ->range(0, 10)
  ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1)); // Run the query as user 1.

$result = $query->execute();

if (isset($result['node'])) {
  $news_items_nids = array_keys($result['node']);
  $news_items = entity_load('node', $news_items_nids);
}
?>
```

Other resources

- [EntityFieldQuery on api.drupal.org](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7)
- [Building Energy.gov without Views](http://treehouseagency.com/blog/neil-hastings/2011/09/06/building-energygov-without-views)